# scala spark conversion error when creating dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, casting

I am a newbie in scala. Please be patient.

I have this code.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, Dataset, SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.ml.clustering.KMeans
import org.apache.spark.ml.evaluation._
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vectors
import org.apache.spark.ml.evaluation.ClusteringEvaluator

// create spark session
implicit val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("clustering").getOrCreate()

// read file
val fileName = """file:///some_location/head_sessions_sample.csv"""

// create DF from file
val df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").load(fileName)

def inputKmeans(df: DataFrame,spark: SparkSession): DataFrame = {
    try {
      val a = df.select("id", "start_ts", "duration", "ip_dist").map(r => (r.getInt(0), Vectors.dense(r.getDouble(1), r.getDouble(2), r.getDouble(3)))).toDF("id", "features")
      a
    }
    catch {
      case e: java.lang.ClassCastException => spark.emptyDataFrame
   }
}


val t = inputKmeans(df).filter( _ != null )
t.foreach(r =>
            if (r.get(0) != null)
              println(r.get(0)))
```

For the moment, i want to ignore my conversion errors. But somehow, I still have them.

> 2018-09-24 11:26:22 ERROR Executor:91 - Exception in task 0.0 in stage
>   4.0 (TID 6) java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Double

I dont think there is any point to give a snapshot of the csv. At this point, i just want to ignore conversion errors. 
Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Take a look at `Vectors.dense(r.getDouble(1), r.getDouble(2), r.getDouble(3)))` -  one of the values is not `Double`. If you want to keep this code like this don't infer the schema, but provide an explicit one. But really, use `VectorAssembler`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, the issue is because the values are not Double type.

```
val a = df.select("id", "start_ts", "duration", "ip_dist").map(r => (r.getInt(0), Vectors.dense(r.getDouble(1), r.getDouble(2), r.getDouble(3)))).toDF("id", "features")
```

Either cast to the **Correct DataType i.e Long Type** (you can also provide the Schema explicitly using Case Class and apply the schema to DataFrame).

Or use the **VectorAssembler** to convert the columns into features. This is easier and recommended approach.

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler 
def inputKmeans(df: DataFrame,spark: SparkSession): DataFrame = {
  val assembler = new VectorAssembler().setInputCols(Array("start_ts", "duration", "ip_dist")).setOutputCol("features")
  val output = assembler.transform(df).select("id", "features")
  output
}
```

Comment: 1 "Either cast to the Correct DataType i.e Long Type (you can also provide the Schema explicitly using Case Class and apply the schema to DataFrame)" Can you lease provide an example?

Comment: 2 and how does assembler  work with my kmeans? i can just apply kmeans.fit(output) ? any other model that demands fitting for that matter? model.fit(output) ?

Comment: VectorAssembler converts the input columns into features vector, so it is similar to constructing the Vector manually as you did above. You can apply the kmeans.fit() on the output dataframe.

Comment: kmeans = KMeans().setK(2).setSeed(1) // example with 2 clusters
model = kmeans.fit(output)

Answer (score 0):

i think i discovered the problem. the "try catch" is placed at the level of the DF creation, not at the level of the conversion. in consequence, it catches problems related to DF creation, not conversion issues.